# Reseed identity column in SQL Compact

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

Is it possible to reset the identity column in a compact database? I'm finding lots of answers regarding standard SQL Server, but no definitive answer regarding if it is possible using SQL CE.

Dropping and recreating the table is not ideal in my scenario!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [Id] IDENTITY (1,1)
```