# How to automatically empty a table every 4 hours?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

in my other question; I asked if it's possible to empty a table when it reaches an amount of records, but there was no answer that could help me with the problem I am facing. 
In this question, I just want to know if it's possible to empty a table every 4 hours.

My database name: **db181894**

My table name: **db181894_names**

Daily records: **A few thousands**

Why do I want to empty the table every 4 hours? Because if I don't, it will show an **500 Internal Error** to the users after they click the form submit button.

So, is it possible to empty a table every 4 hours & how?

Thanks.

Comment: Create a scheduled event

Comment: put your "truncate" query as a cron job

Comment: How'd you come up with 4 hours?

Comment: One idea is to create a table, fill it, then update the oldest row

Comment: Yes, there are thousands of UNIQUE records. None of the records are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial duplicate of [How to delete all data in a table in SQL CE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673013/how-to-delete-all-data-in-a-table-in-sql-ce)

Write a script emptying the table.

Run the script via a CRON job every 4 hours.

Comment: Can you please help me with the script that empties the table? Thanks

Comment: Nope, we have answered your question, now you need to learn how to do things like that.

Comment: Thanks, I will do the DELETE FROM `Names` script :)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it make more sense to fix the **500 Internal Error**?

Anyway, why not run a script via cron that truncates the table every 4 hours?

Comment: On my old web hosting, it was working fine without any 500 Internal Error. But now I changed my web hosting and it's showing when the table has a lot of records.

Comment: There must be something else going on? I suggest trying to find the root of the problem and fixing that. Check logs and turn on errors in PHP to try to narrow down the cause of the issue.

Comment: If you just keep adding records, eventually the table will get large enough to bring even the most industrial strength database to its knees. You will need to periodically trim all (or the oldest) records. I would be concerned though, that a few thousand records are causing your database to go belly up (if that's the real cause). It sounds like you're on a severely underpowered host.